# Why does Jacob defer to his sons in the incidents at Shechem (Genesis 34:5, etc.)?

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible, jacob

When one thinks of the idea of a "patriarch," one thinks of a sort of family absolute monarch, whose wives and children all obey. Jacob does not act that way in the interaction with the Shechemites. His daughter has been raped and kidnapped; yet he waits for his sons to reply to Hamor, the local ruler and father of the rapist. Why? In deferring in this and other ways, did Jacob fail to exercise proper parental authority?

Answer (score 2):

Let us begin by elaborating the problem. Rather than speak one-on-one with Hamor, clan leader to clan leader, Jacob “held his peace until they [his sons] were come.” (Gen 34:5) Then the sons come in from the fields, and “Hamor communed with them,” saying to them—not to Jacob—“I pray you give her him [i.e., to his son, Shechem] to wife.” (34:8) Shechem himself addresses father and sons (34:11); but it is not Jacob, but “the sons of Jacob [who] answered Shechem and Hamor his father” and did so “deceitfully” (34:13) in the presence of their father. They, not Jacob, offer to give their daughters, and to marry the daughters of the Hivites, if only they will be circumcised (34:15-16). (This, by the way, was so appallingly insincere that it counts as a lie; but Jacob stood by and let it happen.) Then it was Simeon and Levi, without consulting Jacob, who proceeded to slaughter the Hivite men (34:25-27). Finally Jacob does chastise his two murderous sons, not to say they have overstepped the bounds of their authority, but to wring his hands over the threat to peace with “the Canaanites and the Perizzites” (Gen 34:30). And the sons dismiss him disrespectfully: “Should he deal with our sister as with an harlot?”

I think we can agree that this is quite a remarkable pattern.

As with Laban taking the lead in marrying off his sister Rebekah in Gen 24, rather than Rebekah's father Bethuel, it was apparently the brothers who took the lead in their sister’s marriage negotiations and, indeed, in defending her honor; see also Gen 24:31-33. I do not know why brothers were given the responsibility of caring for their sisters’ interests in this way; it could have been because brothers would typically have to interact with brothers-in-law in the fields. There might also have been economic considerations: perhaps the brothers were, more than the father, considered key beneficiaries of any significant “bride price.” But these are just speculations.

So Jacob deferred to his sons, perhaps due to a cultural tradition, perhaps for economic reasons. But, whatever the explanation, the 18th century commentator Matthew Henry views this as a failure to exercise proper parental authority: “Things never go well when the authority of a parent runs low in a family.” Is this a fair indictment? It is worth considering.

Jacob could have spoken up and prevented the lie (about the Israelites' intentions to intermarry with the Shechemites) and perhaps also the murder. The fact that Jacob did not suggests that he lacked the courage to stand up to his own angry sons, just as he lacked the courage to face Esau (in Gen 28) and Laban (in Gen 31), and instead opted to run away; he did faced Esau, but only with the Lord’s help and after debasing himself in front of his brother and, probably needlessly, giving him rich gifts.

Though a “usurper” indeed, and though he was by his very name recognized as one who struggled with God himself, his key vice seems to have been cowardice before men. His failure to call upon the Lord for the bravery he needed to stand up to his own sons resulted in their own cowardly deception of the Shechemites, abusing the most significant sign of God’s covenant that the Lord had given them, and finally committing what certainly looks like murder or, in the case of the brothers who helped loot the city (Gen 34:27), abetting murder.